# move in and move out animation in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Please check the below example first

[animation example](http://codecanyon.net/item/multipurpose-bookshelf-slider-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/1985655)

i want to do this in my wpf windows application. plz help me

i am using 3 buttons in grid.row="0"
and three stack panels in grid.row="1"

when user clicks on any button the appropriate stack panel should move in and and other should move out.

I am new to WPF and i tried below.

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="btnPNB" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoard1">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="dbMoveOut" Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelPNB" 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                         From="0" To="600" AutoReverse="False">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="dbMoveIn" Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelOtherBank" 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                         From="-550" To="0" AutoReverse="False">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="btnOther" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoard2">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelOtherBank" 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                         From="-550" To="0" AutoReverse="False">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="btnCAIIB" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoard3">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelCAIIB" 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                         From="-550" To="0" AutoReverse="False">
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <Button x:Name="btnPNB" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="PNB" Click="moveSP_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnOther" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,0,0,0" Content="OTher"  Click="moveSP_Click"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnCAIIB" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,0,0,0" Content="CAIIB" Click="moveSP_Click"></Button>

    <StackPanel x:Name="sPanelPNB" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="-550" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <Image Source="1_1.jpg" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Image>
        <Image Source="1_2.png" Width="100" Margin="50,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Image>
        <Image Source="1_3.png" Width="100" Margin="50,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="sPanelOtherBank" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="-550" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <Image Source="2_1.png" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Image>
        <Image Source="2_2.jpg" Width="100" Margin="50,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Image>
        <Image Source="2_3.png" Width="100" Margin="50,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="sPanelCAIIB" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="-550" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
        <Image Source="3_1.png" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Image>
        <Image Source="3_2.png" Width="100" Margin="50,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Image>
        <Image Source="3_3.jpg" Width="100" Margin="50,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>




</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, what have you tried so far? Show us your code.

Comment: Hello Surfbutler, THanks for ur reply. i updated my question by adding the code.

Comment: Your exemple has plenty of animations..it's misleading..Try to not waste people's time by specifying your issue and what are you expecting.

Comment: i didn't mean to waste any body's time. i want the animation in my application same as shown in example, if you know and want to share then plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want. You have update your panels everytime. And I personally, would add duration. But in this example you will notice your panels if you resize your window

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="btnRed" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoard1">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelRed"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                     To="0"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelBlue"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                     To="-550"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelBlack"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                     To="-550"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="btnBlue" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoard2">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelRed"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                     To="600" AutoReverse="False"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelBlue"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                     To="0"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelBlack"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                     To="-550"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="btnBlack" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoard3">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelRed"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                     To="600"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelBlue"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                     To="600"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelBlack"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                     To="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>

    <Button x:Name="btnRed" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="show red"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnBlue" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,359,0" Content="show blue"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnBlack" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,279,0" Content="show black"></Button>
    <StackPanel x:Name="sPanelRed" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="10" Background="Red">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="-550" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="sPanelBlue" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="10" Background="Blue">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="-550" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="sPanelBlack" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="10" Background="Black">
        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform X="-550" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it was working properly without adding Duration. what i need is that calling the story board on button click event.

Comment: Check HichemC answer - I also tried to set background color of your stackpanels and their height - and it worked (I hope as you expected :))

Comment: Please suggest me the logic to run it properly, it's not working properly.

Comment: Without duration it is too fast (for me). Can you specify - what do you want? You have 2 panels outside, you want them to move - how?

Comment: i got that, Thank you JleruOHeP.

Answer (score 0):

I did simplify your animation to something like this so you can work on it :

```
<Grid>

            <Grid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger SourceName="btnPNB" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoard1">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="dbMoveOut" Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelPNB" 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                         From="0" To="600" AutoReverse="False">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                                <DoubleAnimation x:Name="dbMoveIn" Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelOtherBank" 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                         From="-550" To="0" AutoReverse="False">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger SourceName="btnOther" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoard2">
                            <Storyboard>

                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelOtherBank" 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                         From="-550" To="0" AutoReverse="False">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger SourceName="btnCAIIB" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="StoryBoard3">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="sPanelCAIIB" 
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                         From="-550" To="0" AutoReverse="False">
                                </DoubleAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Grid.Triggers>

            <Button x:Name="btnPNB" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="PNB" ></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnOther" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,0,0,0" Content="OTher"  ></Button>
            <Button x:Name="btnCAIIB" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,0,0,0" Content="CAIIB" ></Button>

            <Grid x:Name="sPanelPNB" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <Border Background="Aquamarine"></Border>
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="sPanelOtherBank" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-550" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Border Background="Blue"></Border>
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="sPanelCAIIB" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-550" Y="0"></TranslateTransform>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Border Background="Violet"></Border>
            </Grid>




        </Grid>
```